# Unlock encrypted computer

Tags: ubuntu, encryption

I have an old HP Pavilion laptop with Ubuntu operating system installed. I haven't needed it for ages and just now tried to log in but have forgotten my password.

The message is "please unlock disk sda5_crypt"

There is nothing on the computer I need so I tried reinstalling the Operating system by booting from a USB with the .iso file download from Ubuntu page. I also tried Win 8.1 .iso which I have the key.

The Bios boot menu has:

- USB Disk 2
- Network Adapter
- Internal CD/DVD Rom Drive
- Notebook Hard Drive

in that order.

I have changed the BIOS booting sequence with the USB first and the HDD at the bottom.

I get the message "an operating system wasn't found"

If I press enter UBUNTU lock screen appears.

My question is there any way to format the drive or defeat the encryption?

Thanks f or any suggestions, cheers

Comment: Please edit your post so that it is clear which messages you get for each of your different approaches.  I.e. Do you get the "Please unlock" message when booting from the USB drive or does something else happen?

Comment: Could this be a "Legacy vs UEFI" kind of issue?   What happens if you disconnect the hard disk and then try to boot just the Flash drive?

Comment: Please tell us exactly how you put the .iso file onto the USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

On a second computer with a Linux OS do the following:

- Download the Ubuntu Install image from [here](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso) or select a i386
  image if that HP doesn't have a 64bit CPU.
- **WARNING!!** Make really sure you know the device of the USB-Stick.
  Otherwise you might override the HDD of your second computer !!!
- In a terminal run `sudo dd if=/path/to/image.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=16M
  status=progress` whereby you have to replace `/path/to/image.iso`
  with the real path to the downloaded image and `dev/sdX` with the
  real device for your USB-Stick.
- Insert the USB-Stick into the old HP.
- Boot the HP into the boot menu and select the USB-Device as boot
  media.
- Install Ubuntu.